# Problem using EnvDTE.Property.set_Value to set ProjectItem FullPath Property

Tags: properties, envdte, projectitem

I have a Visual Studio Project Wizard that attempts to configure a VC# project to override the FullPath property for selected files from the template.

The following code is used from within function

public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)

```
string path = "some file name";
project.ProjectItems.Item("some file").Properties.Item("FullPath").Value = path;
```

System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Invalid number of parameters. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000E (DISP_E_BADPARAMCOUNT))
   at EnvDTE.Property.set_Value(Object lppvReturn)

I know that I have a valid ProjectItem object because I can display the original value.

Comment: Having same problem with a Visual Studio Macro

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the FullPath property is read-only. You can figure this out by looking at the definition in MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.fileproperties.fullpath.aspx - it only has a getter defined.

To call set_Value, you need be updating a property that has a public setter. According to the properties documented on the [FileProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170737.aspx) interface, the only settable properties are:

- [BuildAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.fileproperties.buildaction.aspx)
- [CustomTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.fileproperties.customtool.aspx)
- [CustomToolNamespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.fileproperties.customtoolnamespace.aspx)
- [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.fileproperties.filename.aspx)
- [SubType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.fileproperties.subtype.aspx)